# IIS Manager 7.5 URL rewrite not work on WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, url-rewriting

I added one rule to my service but it's not working. This is in my config file:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="GetSomeData" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="myservice[.]svc[?]info[&amp;]pVersion[=]([^]+)[&amp;]contRep[=]([^]+)[&amp;]docID[=]([^]+)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="myservice.svc/info/pVersion={R:1}&amp;contRep={R:2}&amp;docId={R:3}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
  <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

The "match url" part is working properly, because when I test it in the *Url Rewrite > Test Pattern* form, there it's good.

If I change the action type to *"Redirect"* nothing happens.

If I change this:

```
url="myservice.svc/info/pVersion={R:1}&amp;contRep={R:2}&amp;docId={R:3}"
```

to

```
url="http://www.google.com"
```

or something else, nothing happens.

Append query string is checked (if I uncheck, nothing happens).

What should I set in the IIS Manager or in the WCF config file to make the rewrite or redirect function properly?